# Is it possible for a selected option value to return an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to return an array with two values based on the selected option in a dropdown menu so that I can access it using selectedDate[0] and selectedDate[1] but right now I am getting an array with one long string like ["date1, date2"]. How do I get [date1, date2] instead?

At the top I have:

```
const [ selectedDate, setSelectedDate ] = useState('');
const startDateArray = ['Oct. 18, 2020', 'Oct. 25, 2020'];
const endDateArray = ['Oct. 24, 2020', 'Oct. 31, 2020'];
```

and this is my code:

```
<form>
   <div className="form-group">
      <select className="form-control" id="date-range" disabled={loading} value={selectedDate} 
onChange={(e) => setSelectedDate([e.currentTarget.value)]}>
         {startDateArray.reverse().map((value, index) => (
            <option key={index} value={[moment(value), moment(endDateArray[index])]}>
               {value}-{endDateArray[index]}
            </option>
         ))}
      </select>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why? Just have a lookup object, and put its keys in as the value that you get when an option is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will split the string and make an array out of the individual elements.

It answers this: "*How do I get [date1, date2] instead?*"

```js
const input = ["date1, date2"];
const selectedDate = input[0].split(',').map(s=>s.trim());

console.log(selectedDate[0], selectedDate[1]);
```